# Regularity result related to Heat equation in L. C. Evans PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Related to the heat equation:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
 \begin{cases}
  u_t-\Delta u &= f \text{ in $\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,T]$}\\
   u &= g \text{ on $\mathbb{R}^n\times\{t=0\}$}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Taking the derivative w.r.t. $t$ and setting $\hat{u}:=u_t$
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
 \begin{cases}
  \hat{u}_t-\Delta \hat{u} &= \hat{f} \text{ in $\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,T]$}\\
   \hat{u} &= \hat{g} \text{ on $\mathbb{R}^n\times\{t=0\}$}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
for $\hat{f}:=f_t, \hat{g}:=u_t(\cdot,0)=f(\cdot,0)+\Delta g$. Then multiplying this by $\hat{u}$, integration by parts and applying Gronwall's Lemma will leads to the following result:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
  \sup_{0\leq t\leq T} |u_t|^2 dx+ \int_0^T\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |Du_t|^2 dxdt \leq C\Big(\int_0^T\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f_t^2 dxdt+\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}[|D^2g|^2+f(\cdot,0)^2] dx \Big)
\end{equation}
Where The gronwoll briefly gives as: for $\eta(\cdot)$, non-negative continuous function on $[0,T]$, which satisfies $\eta^{'}(t)\leq \phi(t)\eta(t)+\xi(t)$, for $\phi,\xi$ non-negative. Then $\eta(t)\leq e^{\int_0^T\phi(s) ds}\Big[\eta(0)+\int_0^T\xi(s) ds\Big]$.

I did not quite get exactly how the Gronwall's Lemma applied here, Can someone explain to me how? since I tried to get the inequality for $\hat{u}$ by directly applying Lemma to $(\Delta\hat{u})\hat{u}+f\hat{u}$ in r.h.s but I could not reach the desired result. Can someone explain to me how it applies here?

What I did to get (3) was:

1. multiply (2) by $\hat{u}$ and integrate
   \begin{equation}\tag{4}
      \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\hat{u}_t\hat{u}-\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\Delta \hat{u})\hat{u} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\hat{f}\hat{u}
   \end{equation}
2. reformulate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\hat{u}_t\hat{u}$ as
   \begin{equation}
      \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\hat{u}_t\hat{u} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{d}{dt}\hat{u}^2
   \end{equation}
3. Use integration by parts to $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\Delta \hat{u})\hat{u}$ to obtain:
   \begin{equation}
      \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\Delta \hat{u})\hat{u} = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\nabla\hat{u}\cdot\nabla\hat{u}= -\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|D\hat{u}|^2
   \end{equation}
4. Then I applied the Gronwall to (4) as follows:
   \begin{equation}
      \frac{1}{2}|\hat{u}|^2 \leq e^{\int_0^T\hat{f}(s) ds}\Big[|\hat{u}(\cdot,0)|^2+\int_0^T\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|D\hat{u}|^2 dx ds \Big]
   \end{equation}

And I can apply triangular inequality to $|\hat{u}(\cdot,0)|^2$. But after that I cannot figure out a way to reach $(3)$.

Comment: Can you include the part where you multiply by $\hat{u}$ and integrate by parts? It should be easier to spot the right function $\eta$ then.

Comment: You really should write $\Delta \hat{u} \hat{u}$ as $\hat{u} \Delta \hat{u}$ or $(\Delta \hat{u}) \hat{u}$, though even the last one isn't preferable. And you are missing a negative after the integration by parts on this term.

Comment: @mattos: thanks for pointing me out the mistakes. But what do you mean by the " last one isn't preferable" is it that since I took $\nabla u= Du$

Comment: Sorry, I meant writing $(\nabla \hat{u}) \hat{u}$ still isn't a good notation, even though it is better than writing $\nabla \hat{u} \hat{u}$, and so even it 'isn't preferable'. I wasn't referring to any of the working in your post whatsoever. I haven't been through your question fully, but I'll take a look at it tomorrow if I have time and it hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: @mattos: ok, cool, thanks!